# Alignment in combined OHLC chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

The allignment in the following chart is wrong.

The OHLC data point is exactly in the middle of the volume bar. But the additional TimeSeries starts where the bar starts (the line should connect the lowest point of the OHLC point). How can I center it?

[image: alignment in chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setXPosition` in your dataset

Comment: It is not only an answer but, as far as I can tell from the question, a correct answer.

Comment: full code is myTimeSeriesCollection.setXPosition(TimePeriodAnchor.MIDDLE);